# How do I evaluate this integral by substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I evaluate $$\int \frac{e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-x}} dx$$

I've tried the substitution u = $e^{-x}$, and the furthest I've gotten is $\int \frac{-u}{1+u} du$ and I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: It's actually easier to substitute $u = 1 + e^{-x}$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've already done the hard part. Notice now that
$$\int \frac{u}{1 + u} du = \int \left(1 - \frac{1}{1 + u}\right) du$$

> $$\cdots = u - \log |u + 1| + C.$$

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks! I'll accept your answer once the 10 mins limit is up.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful!

Comment: I am puzzled by the nearly simultaneous downvotes on both my answer and Sami's very good answer...

Comment: @Travis $\ln|x|$ is not an antiderivative of $\frac1x$. It works only on $(0,\infty)$, $(-\infty,0)$, not both. Maybe you think this is obvious and not worth mentioning. But I don't like it and that's my reason, nothing more.

Comment: @user2345215 That's untrue: Since $\frac{d}{dx} \log |x| = \frac{1}{x}$, $\log|x|$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ by definition. I think you're confusing this with the related issue of evaluating definite integrals using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which indeed requires a hypothesis like continuity (though one can weaken this some).

Comment: @Travis Why didn't you include $\ln|x|+c_1\chi_{x<0}+c_2\chi_{x>0}$ then? They are antiderivatives too, right? Maybe you now see why I don't like it written like that.

Comment: You're correct that, since $\log|x|$ is not connected, the general antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is the set of functions given by $\log|x| + C$ on $(-\infty, 0)$ and $\log|x| + D$ on $(0, \infty)$ for some constants $C, D$. But, nearly every calculus reference will suppress this complication, because in settings where the constant of integration is essential, one is already typically only working on one connected component of the domain, and good references justify this by declaring that expressions $+ C$ refer to working with one such component at a time, which is the sense I had in mind.

Comment: Travis: the downvoters are jealous that your answer is the best! +1 to counter the downvotes.

Comment: @Joao Cheers! I was mostly just puzzled given that the question (and answer) are both so standard. Still, it is good to remind oneself from time to time of the sort of technical points that user2345215 mentions.

Answer (score 7):

$$\int\frac{-u}{1+u}du=\int\frac{-u\color{red}{-1+1}}{1+u}du=-\int du+\int\frac{du}{1+u}=-u+\ln|1+u|+C$$